# How to use a variable value as string inside nested php function call

Tags: php

I am not at all expert in php. Working in a drupal view, I need to conditionally format several fields. To get sanitized node values I can use:

```
$thsField = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_first');
$output = field_view_value('node', $node,  'field_first',$thsField[0]);
```

but since I have to do this numerous times I wanted to use a function which I can pass the field names into. Something like

```
$node = node_load($data->nid);
function getValue($var)
  {
    $thsfield = field_get_items('node', $node, $var);
    $fieldvalue = field_view_value('node', $node, $var,$thsfield[0]);
    return $fieldvalue;
  }
```

But am having no luck. Is there some way special way to have the string value of $var be understood in this usage, or am I doing something fundamentally wrong according to php? (edit: added node def - which WAS already present in my test. The $node and $data values are definitely populated and in scope)

I think there may be something I'm not understanding about php scope (or Drupal access permissions?). If I do this:

```
function getValue()
{
    $node = node_load($data->nid);
    $thsfield = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_first_author');
    $thsvalue =  field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_first_author',$thsfield[0]);
    print render($thsvalue);
}
```

I get this error: "ResponseText: EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids()"

If I comment out the function name and brackets, it prints the value as expected.

Comment: The fundamental one - where's `$node` defined in that method?

Comment: You can use global $node; or even define function getValue($var, $node)

Comment: @Alex using `global` is almost always a good sign of a bad design

Comment: And Drupal doesn't have a global `$node` object either, so even less reason to try using it

Comment: Most likely you need to pass `$data->nid` into the function.

Comment: Ok, thanks all, it was scope - I added $node as a passed variable and it works fine. Should I edit and leave it to be marked solved?

Comment: Either delete it or self answer.

Answer (score 0):

This was a scope issue, no problem with php interpreting variables. Changing the fn to:

```
function getValue($var,$node)
 {
   $thsfield = field_get_items('node', $node, $var);
   $fieldvalue = field_view_value('node', $node, $var,$thsfield[0]);
   return $fieldvalue;
 }
```

worked!